# Http verb of current http context

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpcontext, http-verbs

How do you find the http verb (POST,GET,DELETE,PUT) used to access your application? Im looking [httpcontext.current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) but there dosent seem to be any property that gives me the info. Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx

Answer (score 9):

In ASP.NET CORE 2.0 you can get (or set) the HTTP verb for the current context using:

```
Request.HttpContext.Request.Method
```

Answer (score 7):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post.Method) 
{
        // The action is a post 
}
    
if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.put.Method)
{
        // The action is a put 
}

if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.DELETE.Method)
{
        // The action is a DELETE
}

if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Get.Method)
{
        // The action is a Get
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use: `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requesttype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For getting Get and Post

```
string method = HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core v3.1 I retrieve the current HTTP verb by using the HttpContextAccessor interface which is injected in on the constructor, e.g.

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyPage(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Usage:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod` return string, but better use enum [HttpVerbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It seems there are no build in method to get currrent verb as enum, so I wrote helper for it

Helper class

```
public static class HttpVerbsHelper
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<HttpVerbs, string> Verbs =
            new Dictionary<HttpVerbs, string>()
            {
                {HttpVerbs.Get, "GET"},
                {HttpVerbs.Post, "POST"},
                {HttpVerbs.Put, "PUT"},
                {HttpVerbs.Delete, "DELETE"},
                {HttpVerbs.Head, "HEAD"},
                {HttpVerbs.Patch, "PATCH"},
                {HttpVerbs.Options, "OPTIONS"}
            };

        public static HttpVerbs? GetVerb(string value)
        {
            var verb = (
                from x in Verbs
                where string.Compare(value, x.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                select x.Key);
            return verb.SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

base controller class of application

```
public abstract class BaseAppController : Controller
    {
        protected HttpVerbs? HttpVerb
        {
            get
            {
                var httpMethodOverride = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.GetHttpMethodOverride();
                return HttpVerbsHelper.GetVerb(httpMethodOverride);
            }
        }
}
```