# Building a HttpContext for testing, how can I specify the HttpRequest is a POST?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, httprequest, httphandler

I'm writing some unit tests for a method that takes an HttpContext as a parameter.  I want to test that the behavior is as expected when the request is a POST.

When creating a System.Net.HttpWebRequest it's easy to set the method, but I can't see a way to specify the method when creating a System.Web.HttpRequest which is what's used in HttpContext.

Any ideas?

For context the method is called by an httphandler and it is supposed to throw a 405 if the request is not a POST.  I know that I can filter the allowable methods with the Verbs property in the web.config, and I will, however there's nothing stopping somebody in the future from changing the verbs property to allow other methods in which case I want the handler to take care of it itself.

Helper method currently in use:

```
    private HttpContext GetHttpContext(string requestUrl)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", requestUrl, "");            
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        return new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);
    }
```

Comment: Use HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.  Via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898598/http-verb-of-current-http-context

Comment: HttpMethod is a getter only, not a setter, so won't work for testing.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I just read somewhere that `HttpContext.Current` is writeable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend researching mocking objects for the purpose of unit testing.  There are a few mocking frameworks available for .NET that facilitate exactly this type of test.

For example, the article [here](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/extending-steve-sandersone28099s-contextmocks-class) sets the HttpMethod using the Moq framework.

From the article:

```
public ContextMocks(Controller onController, string HTTPMethod)
{
    //...
    Request = new Moq.Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    Request.Setup(x => x.HttpMethod).Returns(HTTPMethod);
    //...
}
```

That said, if this is a one-off test, and I can't stress that enough, and the overhead incurred by introducing object mocking is unnecessary in your particular situation, the following reflection will set the HttpMethod:

```
typeof(HttpRequest).GetField("_httpMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(httpRequest, "POST");
```

As I mentioned previously, if testing with `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest`, etc. are or will become a recurring theme, then take advantage of a mocking framework.  You will save yourself time in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it last night and figured if there was no easier method I would have to just use reflection, but wanted to avoid that option if I could as there's no guarantee of a private field existing after a version change.  I figured mocking would be what i'd have to do, was just hoping it wasn't required and I as just missing something.

Comment: Well looks like i'm stuck using reflection, HttpRequest is sealed so I can't mock it.  This is not an MVC app so the context uses HttpRequest instead of HttpRequestBase...